# Using of \multirow with alignment in longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow, multicolumn

I've made a longtable  [image: LONGTABLE 1]
and now try to add sells "lang1-2-3-4" like here:[image: TABLE 2]

Could you please correct my code for longtable.

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
   \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[turkish,russian]{babel}
  %\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
  %\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif

  \usepackage{fontenc}
  \usepackage{longtable}
  \usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage[overwrite=true]{getmap}
  \usepackage{calc}

  \usepackage[unicode,hidelinks]{hyperref}
  \usepackage{geometry} % Меняем поля страницы
  \geometry{left=1.5cm}% левое поле
  \geometry{right=1.5cm}% правое поле
  \geometry{top=1.5cm}% верхнее поле
  \geometry{bottom=1.5cm}% нижнее поле

  \newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}

 {\obeylines\gdef^^M{^^J}%
  \catcode`\@=0 %
  \catcode`\\=12 %
  @gdef@n{\n}}



  %\newcommand*{\pin}{%pincode map
 %  \includegraphics[height=\heightof{M}]{pincode}%
  %}

 \begin{document}
    \shorthandoff{=}
    \large

    \pagestyle{empty}

 %LONGTABLE 1

 \begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}*{\minitab[c]{\textbf{1 April,} \\ \textbf{Friday}}} &\textbf{9.00} "--- event 1.\\
& \textbf{18.00} "--- event 2.\\
\hline
\multirow{3}*{\minitab[c]{\textbf{ 2 April,} \\ \textbf{Saturday}}} & \textbf{8.00} "--- event 1.\\
& \textbf{9.00} "--- event 2.\\
& \textbf{18.00} "--- event 3.\\
\hline
\multirow{4}*{\minitab[c]{\textbf{3 April,} \\ \textbf{Sunday}}} & \textbf{Event EventEventEventEvent EventEvent Event EventEvent.}\\
&\textbf{8.00} "--- event 1.\\
&\textbf{9.00} "--- event 2.\\
\hline
\multirow{2}*{\minitab[c]{\textbf{6 April,} \\ \textbf{Wednesday}}} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}[0cm][0cm]{\textbf{18.00} "--- event 1.}\\
& \\
\hline

\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That complicated definition for `\n` is much more easily carried out with `\edef\n{\string\n}`; I don't understand the redefinition of the active `^^M`, though. It looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, not using multirow, but `makecell` and `tabularx`. I define a new column type (`D`) which enters each cell in a suitable `itemize` environment. `Makecell` ensures you can break lines in cells, and their content is horizontally and vertically centred. Finally, with the `ltablex` package, a `tabularx` environment can break across pages.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
   \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[turkish,russian]{babel}
  %\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
  %\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif

  \usepackage{fontenc}
  \usepackage{longtable}
  \usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{array}
 % \usepackage[overwrite=true]{getmap}
  \usepackage{calc}

  \usepackage[unicode,hidelinks]{hyperref}
  \usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % Меняем поля страницы
  \geometry{left=1.5cm}% левое поле
  \geometry{right=1.5cm}% правое поле
  \geometry{top=1.5cm}% верхнее поле
  \geometry{bottom=1.5cm}% нижнее поле

  \newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}

 {\obeylines\gdef^^M{^^J}%
  \catcode`\@=0 %
  \catcode`\\=12 %
  @gdef@n{\n}}



  %\newcommand*{\pin}{%pincode map
 % \includegraphics[height=\heightof{M}]{pincode}%
  %}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\itemize[leftmargin=2.5em, labelsep=0pt, font=\bfseries, align=right]} X <{\enditemize\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+ \topsep\relax}}}
\usepackage{enumitem, ragged2e, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \shorthandoff{=}
    \large

    \pagestyle{empty}

 %LONGTABLE 1
\keepXColumns
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}| D|}%
\hline
\thead{1 April, \\ Friday \\[2ex]
 \hspace*{-\tabcolsep}\begin{tabular}{ p{\dimexpr0.1\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} |p{\dimexpr0.1\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}}%
\hline
 lang1 & lang 2\\
 \hline
 lang3 & lang4\\[-1.5ex]
 \end{tabular} } &%
\item[9.00] "--- event 1 %
\item[18.00] "--- event 2.
 \\
\hline
\thead{ 2 April, \\ Saturday } & %
\item[8.00] "--- event 1.%
 \item[9.00] "--- event 2.%
 \item[18.00] "--- event 3.\\
\hline
\thead{3 April, \\ Sunday } & \item[]\textbf{Event EventEventEventEvent EventEvent Event EventEvent.} \item[8.00] "--- event 1.%
\item[9.00] "--- event 2. \\%
\hline
\thead{6 April, \\ Wednesday} &\item[18.00] "--- event 1.
  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]